# Express JS not serving few static files, throws 500 internal server error

Tags: node.js, angular, express, nginx-reverse-proxy

When express server is started with SPA application index file and few other static files are loaded and some files throw 500 error
[image]

NodeJS server is running, and serving the static files from the correct folder. (This can be confirmed as it loads index.html and some other assets)
[image]

As seen from the network tab scripts.2d2e0c1a64a29c086e01.js, jspdf.min.js, favicon are loaded from the same static folder, but other js files are not loaded.
[image]

When error files are opened with full link (localhost:3000/main-es2015.b21fb6bfbdb8538cc020.js) these files are also loaded aswell.

The static folder contains the build files from angular 8.
Same issue when tried with nginx reverse proxy config.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: *When error files are opened with full link* - what would be the opposite that causes the issue? Your first image shows 500 and a full link as well.

Comment: When I try to open the broken link in the separate tab(like http://localhost:3000/runtime-es2015.2d6e2878da7137a51e30.js), I can load the script. But won't load when initiated by index.html

Comment: Have you tried to inspect what actual **absolute uri** is used in the latter case?

Comment: Yes, I tried by replacing them with absolute paths. It's the same.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the new URL wasn't allowed in the Content Security Policy list, once adding it everything works as expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error -- HTTP 500 when requesting an image from Express -- and corrected it by granting more permission to the static files. When the error was happening, the image file had permissions -rw-rw----. I used sudo chmod 666 public/static/*.jpg to change this to -rw-rw-rw-, and the problem was solved.